# Access previous element with iterator

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

The idea is that I have a list of words and the user searches for a word on the list and then depending on what the word is you either print off the following or the preceding word. It was simple enough to do it with the following word like so :

```
public void pirateToEnglish(){
        System.out.println("Enter the word that you want to translate ");
        String nameSearch;
        nameSearch=input.nextLine();

        Iterator<Phrase> it = phrases.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            Phrase c = it.next();
            if (c.getName().equals(nameSearch))  {
                System.out.println( it.next().toString());      
                return;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("not on list");
    }
```

But I'm struggling to do this with the preceding word because the iterator has no previous method. Any ideas on how to get this to work would be very appreciated

Comment: Is this a homework ? If yes, shouldn't you do it by yourself, to learn ?

Answer (score 3):

try [ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) instead of `Iterator`.  `ListIterator` has [previous()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#previous%28%29) method to access the previous element in the list.

```
ListIterator<Phrase> iterator = phrases.listIterator();
Phrase p = iterator.previous();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator%28%29). A ListIterator is able to iterate in both directions.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `ListIterator` or save the previous item in a variable inside your loop.

Another issue - calling `it.next()` twice is unsafe as you only check `it.hasNext()` once.

Answer (score 0):

You can store previous element in a string like this:

```
 String previous = "";
 while(it.hasNext())
    {
        Phrase c = it.next();
        if (c.getName().equals(nameSearch))  {
            System.out.println( "Previous : " + previous); 
            System.out.println( "Next : " + it.next().toString());      
            return;
        }
        previous = c.getName(); //Convert current element to String or c.getName() whichever is applicable.
    }
```

Comment: This should be "Next : " + c.toString());